# rails Import csv file, but saving blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

My github address https://github.com/ParkHyunDo/ImportCsv

I am studying how to import an excel file using roo. The import works fine, but everything is blank.
Like this....

[image]

Here is my code

## product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(accepts_nested_attributes_for)
      product.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      # You're using a tab seperated file, so specify seperator as a tab with \t
      when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, csv_options: {col_sep: "\t"})
      when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
      when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
      else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end


end
```

## products_controller.rb

```
def import
  Product.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

Please help me!

Comment: What is exactly blank? Are the records being saved correctly? Is it problem with a view? If so post it's code too.

Comment: I did upload screenshot that views blank. please click 'enter image description here' .

Comment: How can anybody know what is wrong with a view, if you do not provide code for it?

Comment: Showing sample csv data could help too.

Comment: https://github.com/ParkHyunDo/ImportCsv

Comment: This is my github! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems strange:

```
product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(accepts_nested_attributes_for)
```

The class method `accepts_nested_attributes_for` has a completely different purpose than listing the attribute names of `Product`. But you could use `attribute_names`. Try this:

```
product.attributes = row.to_hash.stringify_keys.slice(*attribute_names)
```

Note that `stringify_keys` might be unnecessary, depending on how exactly the hash returned by `row.to_hash` looks. Also note that slice takes a list of attribute names, not an array. The asterisk `*` allows us to use the elements of an array as individual arguments to a function.